# How To Return A Custom Error While Using Credentials In Next-Auth v5.0.0-beta.5

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, app-router

please i am currently using next-auth@5.0.0-beta.5 to handle user authentication in my nextJs app. i want to be able to send a custom error to the client when a user authentication fails while using credentials.

I have tried doing this which use to work in the version 4:

```
     async authorize(credentials: any) {
                let urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();

                urlencoded.append('email', credentials.email);
                urlencoded.append('password', credentials.password);
                const res = await AuthApiInstance.signIn<UserSchemaType>(urlencoded);

                console.log(res);

                if (res.isError && !res.resData) {
                    throw new Error(JSON.stringify({ errors: res.error, status: res.statusCode }))
                };

                if (res.resData?.data.token) {
                    encryptCookieDataAction(res.resData?.data.token, EncryptionCookiesKeys.AdminToken)
                }

                return res.resData?.data as any
            },
```

but it doesn't work anymore.

Please I would really appreciate it if anybody could help with how I can go about sending a custom error back to the client when using credentials.